# The proof that the direct product of abelian groups is an $R$-module under a certain action .

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing, modules

I know that the direct product of abelian groups is abelian, it remains to show that the given action is well defined which is trivial and as follows:
$$r\{a_{i}\} = r\{b_{i}\} \Rightarrow \{ra_{i}\} = \{rb_{i}\} \Rightarrow \{a_{i}\} = \{b_{i}\} $$

1- Is the above proof of welldefinedness right?

2-Now I am not sure exactly why by the given action ${ra_{i}}$ is necessarily in $A$, could anyone explain this for me please?

3-Finally I have to prove that:

$\forall$ r,s $\in R$ and a,b $\in A$:

(i)$ r(a + b) = ra + rb  \Leftrightarrow r (\{a_{i} + b_{i}\}) = r\{a_{i}\} + r\{b_{i}\} $

**Proof:**

$l.h.s = r (\{a_{i} + b_{i}\}) = (r\{a_{i} + b_{i}\}) = (\{ra_{i} +r b_{i}\}) = (\{ra_{i}\} + \{rb_{i}\}) = r\{a_{i}\} + r\{b_{i}\}$ = r.h.s

Is the previous proof right?

(ii)$(r + s)\{a_{i}\} = \{(r+s)a_{i}\}.$

**Proof:**
I do not know what to write in this proof, could anyone do it for me please?

(iii)$r(s{a_{i}}) = (rs){a_{i}}$

**Proof:**

Also do not know what to write in this proof, could anyone help me please?

[image]

Comment: What is $R$ (this matters) and what is the definition of the action (this matters)?

Comment: Oh, you are trying to prove a direct sum of $R$-modules is again an $R$-module?

Comment: @Randall  all informations are stated in the above picture in Theorem 1.11.

Comment: Your title is a completely different problem.

Comment: @Randall no a direct product not a direct sum.

Comment: @Randall no the title is the same as what is required to be proved in Theorem 1.11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof of well definedness is completely backwards.  You assume $r\{a_i\} = r\{b_i\}$ and conclude that $\{a_i\} = \{b_i\}$ which is a false statement and not the statement you want to prove.  You want to prove that $\{a_i\} = \{b_i\}$ implies $r\{a_i\} = r\{b_i\}$ and if you just change the $\Rightarrow$'s to $\Leftarrow$'s you'll have a correct proof of that fact.  I should point out, though, that there's no need to prove well definedness.  Well definedness is something you prove when your definition seems to depend on an arbitrary choice and you want to show that the result is the same no matter what choice is made.  The definition of the action on a direct product does not involve equivalence classes or anything of that sort so there are no choices to be made in the definition.  The definition is just a formula for what the action is and that formula is perfectly well defined a priori.

You do, on the other hand, have to prove that the formula satisfies the axioms of an $R$-module action.  This is what you should be checking in i, ii, and iii of 3.  In 3.i the statement of what you should be proving is wrong.  You're just proving $r(a + b) = ra + rb$, you don't need an iff.  After you set $a = \{a_i\}$ and $b = \{b_i\}$ then you get that the goal is to prove $r\{a_i + b_i\} = r\{a_i\} + r\{b_i\}$, and what you've written correctly proves that.

Backtracking a bit now, in 2 you ask why $ra_i$ is in $A$.  The answer is it's not, $A$ is the product of the $A_i$ and if $a_i \in A_i$ then the tuple $\{a_i\}$ is in $A$, but $a_i$ is not in $A$.  Similarly, since $A_i$ and $A$ are $R$-modules $ra_i \in A_i$ and $r\{a_i\} = \{ra_i\} \in A$, but $ra_i$ is not in $A$.

Finally, for 3.ii and 3.iii I think you have the statements of what you want to prove a little mixed up.  For ii you want $(r + s)a = ra + sa$ which becomes $(r + s)\{a_i\} = r\{a_i\} + s\{a_i\}$ after you set $a = \{a_i\}$.  Similarly in iii you want to prove $(rs)a = r(sa)$ which becomes $(rs)\{a_i\} = r(s\{a_i\})$.  The strategy for proving those is exactly the strategy you used in 3.i, move everything inside the braces and use associativity and distributivity while inside the braces.

Comment: Can you check also this question for me please when you have time? thanks in advance.

Comment: Amazing! so clear explanation.